# Using MaterialStateProperty for Normal Properties

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

I'm building an InputChip in Flutter and I want to use different MaterialStates to change the properties. In the InputChip shape description it says,

> This shape is combined with [side] to create a shape decorated with
> an outline. If it is a [MaterialStateOutlinedBorder],
> [MaterialStateProperty.resolve] is used for the following
> [MaterialState]s:
>
> [MaterialState.disabled]. [MaterialState.selected].
> [MaterialState.hovered]. [MaterialState.focused].
> [MaterialState.pressed].

But I haven't figured out how to use a MaterialStateProperty for the shape. The code I tried is:

```
InputChip(
    shape: MaterialStateProperty<OutlinedBorder?>.resolve(getBorder),
)

OutlinedBorder? getBorder(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    return RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12), side: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary));
  }
```

And the error I'm getting is:

> The argument type 'MaterialStateProperty<OutlinedBorder?>' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'OutlinedBorder?'

Any idea how I can resolve MaterialStates into a OutlinedBorder? for this property?

Answer (score 0):

`OutlinedBorder` itself a `MaterialStateProperty`. You can do

```dart
InputChip(
  shape: getBorder({}),
)
```